# Makefile does not read the rest

Tags: c++, g++, makefile

I have a problem with make file. It does not continue to read after creating the first `.o` file. Here is my make file:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -g
LDFLAGS = -lm

PokerEval.o: PokerEval.cpp
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c PokerEval.cpp

random.o: random.cpp random.h
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c random.cpp

myprogram: random.o PokerEval.o
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} PokerEval.o random.o ${LDFLAGS} -o myprogram

clean:
    rm -f myprogram *.o
.PHONY: all clean
```

So when I run it all I get is this:

```
$ make
g++ -g -c PokerEval.cpp
```

Answer (score 2):

Make normally<sup>1</sup> builds the *first* target in the makefile unless you specify a target on the command line.

Therefore, you normally specify your main target (e.g., the executable) first, then whatever it depends upon after that.

Note that you can (and frequently do) define *macros* before the first target -- they don't count as a target.

---

1. "Normally" in this case meaning "always, with a properly designed make utility". The exception is an ancient Microsoft tool that they called make, but which built *everything*, regardless. Their current `nmake` ("new make") that works (at least semi-) correctly has been around for decades now though.